# Corollary of high-dimensional Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $G\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is an open, path-connected set. If the function $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$ is
> differentiable in the domain $G$ and its differential equals zero at
> every point $x\in G$, then $f$ is constant in the domain $G$,
>
> **Proof.** We first show that if $x\in G$, then the function $f$ is constant in a ball $B(x;r)\subset G$. Indeed, if $x+h\in B(x;r)$, then
> $[x,x+h]\subset B(x;r)\subset G$. Applying high-dimensional version of
> Mean Value Theorem, we obtain $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(\xi)h=0\cdot h=0,$$
> that is, $f(x+h)=f(x)$, and the values of $f$ in the ball $B(x;r)$ are
> all equal to the value at the center of the ball.
>
> Now let $x_0,x_1\in G$ be arbitraru points of the domain $G$. By the
> path-connectedness of $G$, there exists a path $\Gamma:[0,1]\to G$
> such that $\Gamma(0)=x_0$ and $\Gamma(1)=x_1$. Let $B(x_0;r)$ be a
> ball with center at $x_0$ contained in $G$. Since $\Gamma(0)=x_0$ and
> the mapping $\Gamma(t)$ is continuous, there is a positive number
> $\delta_0\in(0,1)$ such that $\Gamma(t)\in B(x_0;r)\subset G$ for
> $t\in [0,\delta_0]$. Then, by what has been proved, $(f\circ
>  \Gamma)(t)\equiv f(x_0)$ on the interval $[0,\delta_0]$.
>
> Let $\ell=\sup \mathcal{C}$, where
> $$\mathcal{C}:=\{\delta\in(0,1]:f(\Gamma(t))=f(x_0) \ \forall t\in
>  [0,\delta]\}.$$ Obviously this supremum exists because $\mathcal{C}$
> is bounded above and $\mathcal{C}\neq \varnothing$ since $\delta_0\in
>  \mathcal{C}$. By the continuity of the function $f(\Gamma(t))$ we have
> $f(\Gamma(\ell))=f(x_0)$. But then, $\ell=1$. Indeed, if that were not
> so, we could take a ball $B(\Gamma(\ell);r)\subset G$, in which the
> value of function $f$ is equal to $f(\Gamma(\ell))=f(x_0)$, and then
> by continuity of the mapping $\Gamma$ find $\Delta>0$ such that
> $\Gamma(t)\in B(\Gamma(\ell);r)$ for $t\in [\ell,\ell+\Delta]$. But
> then $(f\circ \Gamma)(t)=f(\Gamma(\ell))=f(x_0)$ for $t\in
>  [0,\ell+\Delta]$, and so $\ell\neq \sup \delta$.
>
> Since $\sup \mathcal{C}=1$, then $f(\Gamma(1))=f(x_0)$ which implies
> that $f(x_1)=f(x_0)$. Hence $f\equiv \text{const}$ on $G$.

I think I undestood the technical side of the proof but I need to emphasize it is not so trivial as in one-dimensional setting. However, I am little confused and I am not grasping the general idea behind the proof. Firstly, we have shown that in any small ball inside the $G$ the function is constant and I understood that. However, I have a

**Question 1.** What is the idea of this $\sup \mathcal{C}$? Can anyone explain it in a simpler way rather than some formula?

**Question 2** What is the general idea of this proof? I am confused with this supremum stuff.

In each theorem I am trying to understand the idea and that is why I am asking this question. Thank you so much!

Comment: The supremum tries to find "turning point" after which $f$ stops being constant. This point is found along the continuous curve $\Gamma$. Proving that that supremum is equal to 1 is equivalent to saying that $f$ is constant on the image of $\Gamma$. The general idea is that you can connect any 2 points with a path, so since $f$ is constant along it, both ends must take the same value.

Comment: A much simpler proof is obtained by joining a fixed point to the general point by a piecewise-differentiable path. Then just apply the single-variable chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain the idea behind the proof a bit. A picture might also help here (I provide one for $n=2$). So we start by taking two arbitrary points $x_0, x_1 \in G$ and we want to show that $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$. Since $G$ is connected there is a continuous curve $\Gamma: [0,1] \to G$ that connects $x_0$ and $x_1$.

The first part asserts that if we move a little away from $x_0$ along the curve $\Gamma$ the value of $f$ does not change. Then we want to find the most we can move away from $x_0$ along $\Gamma$ such that the value of $f$ remains the same (and equal to $f(x_0)$). By most, I mean in terms of the parameter of $\Gamma$ (and not euclidean distance) which you can think of as time.

This is measured by $\ell$. Now it should be clear that we want $\ell$ to be equal to $1$ for $f(x_0) = f(x_1)$ to hold. If $\ell < 1$ then we can take a ball around $\Gamma(\ell)$ in which $f$ will be constant and equal to $f(\Gamma(\ell)) = f(x_0)$ (this is the same argument as in the first step). But then we could move just a little more along $\Gamma$ without leaving this ball. This implies that  $f(\Gamma(\ell + \Delta))$ would be equal to $f(x_0)$ for some small $\Delta$, contradicting the property of $\ell$. So indeed $\ell = 1$ and $f$ is constant along $\Gamma$ and in particular, $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$.

Here is the drawing, for some geometric intuition:

[image]

**Remark:** There is also a simpler proof provided you are familiar with the fact that an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected. In that case, it suffices to prove that $f$ is constant along line segments, which is a direct consequence of the high-dimensional mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks  lot for your reply! I am reading it now. Why is it obvious that $\ell$ should be equal to $1$? I know that it follows from $f(\Gamma(\ell))=f(x_0)$ but even the last equality does not follow immediately.

Comment: @ZFR $\ell$ is the longest we can travel along $\Gamma$ without the value of $f$ chaning. In order to reach $x_1$ we need to travel all of $\Gamma$ so $\ell$ should be $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Now it makes sense. As far as I understood, $\ell$ is the longest from $x_0$ (in terms of parameter) such that $f$ does not change the value.

Comment: @ZFR Yeah that's exactly what is measured by $\ell$.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer.